# Get position of scrollbar with iscrollview jquerymobile plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iscroll, iscrollview

The Html :

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1 class="header">Index page</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="example-wrapper" data-iscroll>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some link</a></li>                
              </ul>
        </div>          
    </div>

    <div data-theme="b" data-role="footer">
        <h1><a href="#" class="top">Footer</a></h1>
    </div>    
</div>
```

The following is the javascript to move the scrollbar. But i want to retrieve the position of the scrollbar after it has moved:

```
$(document).on('click','a.top',function(){   
    $(".example-wrapper").iscrollview("scrollTo", 0, 100, 200, true);
    console.log($('.iscroll-wrapper').iscrollview('option','y'));
});
```

Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathvarun/sdag7/).

Answer (score 1):

iScrollview wraps content in a `.iscroll-scroller` div, and uses `transform()` to scroll that div. You need to retrieve `transform` CSS property of the aforementioned div.

```
$(".iscroll-scroller").css("transform");
```

The above will return a [`matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#matrix), and `y` carries the value of vertical transform/translate. Then you need to `.split(" ")` *matrix* and convert it into an *array* to be able to read it.

```
var matrix = $(".iscroll-scroller").css("transform").split(" ");
```

The *array* will look like this

```
["matrix(1,", "0,", "0,", "1,", "0,", "-100)"]
```

Then just `parseInt(string, radix)` last value in *array*, (`matrix.length - 1` = index of last value).

```
var posY = parseInt(matrix[matrix.length - 1], 10);
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/heLr2/)** <sup>(1)</sup>

<sup>(1)</sup> `setTimeout()` is used in demo to delay retrieving `posY` after animation (transform) is done.

Comment: Thanks mate though i was hoping the answer wouldn't requrie a hackish approach.Seems like the plugin applies a padding of its own causing the scrollbar position to never indicate 0. Anyway to detect bottom/top of page ?

Comment: @nathvarun you're welcome. What do you mean by detect top/bottom of page? Offset?

Comment: I want to detect when the scrollbar has reached the bottom of the page i.e user has scrolled to the last element.

Comment: @nathvarun in this case you need to calculate scrollable div height, wrapper height and scroll position. I'll update my answer with the code later this evening.

Answer (score 1):

Though @omar's answer does get us what we want, after alot of meddling with the code i finally figured it out the easier way.
The iscrollview plugin has a set of getters that can be used to directly access the information needed.

```
$(document).on('click','.top',function(){
    console.log('Scroller Position Y ='+$('.example-wrapper').iscrollview('y'));
    console.log('Scroller Height = '+$('.example-wrapper').iscrollview('scrollerH'));
    console.log('Wrapper Height = '+$('.example-wrapper').iscrollview('wrapperH'));


    });
```

The documentation on the github page of the plugin does not really explain how to use these and thats what was causing the confusion.

***[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nathvarun/sdag7/2/)***